# Generate grammatical analysis of several hundred paragraphs

Tags: parsing, text, grammar, analysis

I have 1,000 (for example) entries of customer support notes that are logged.

Each of these notes (Anything from 25 characters to 500 characters long) have been entered into a system by the user (users will have multiple notes created by them), I'd like to be able to generate an equivalent of a 'grammatical KPI' by analysing the text.

I want to refrain from running a spell-check against them, but rather look at consistency of basic grammar like capital letters and punctuation (correct punctuation if possible). Including the verbosity of each note to factor into the output of said 'KPI' would be an interesting twist too.

Without indulging into programming languages, what would be the most efficient way/method to create not an 100% accurate representation, but enough to see outliers of the grammar in the notes submitted by these users?

I have no experience with anything like this.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this very much depend upon the level of analysis you intend to do. To find out if every word before a capitalized word has a punctuation character after it wouldn't be so hard. To actually parse the English language and determine some heuristics as to how "good" the sentence is sounds like a very tough problem indeed.

Comment: Well, my original intentions were to create something very rough that essentially did what you just said, check capitalizations and grammar that follows. I intended to scope out a set of basic grammar rules (capitalization after a period, etc) and just run each block through the rules and outputting a numerical value/'score'. I was curious to see if there were more efficient methods or perhaps advice on this task. I'm looking to pick up on outliers, i.e the users that are consistent, so I assume basic implementation is only needed.

Comment: In that case, I would probably just use a lexer to divide the notes up into words and punctuation, and run through the token streams, checking for mismatches according to given rules. Use a generator for the lexer would probably be the easiest and fastest route.

Answer (score 1):

This presentation by the Director of the Python Software Foundation is actually about extracting semantics out of formal documents (patent licenses):

> http://vimeo.com/53058803

This paper describes techniques for extracting the *sentiment* out of written text:

> http://goo.gl/wY9sW